# Display connected users in Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows, ssh, windows-server-2003-r2

I'm SSH'ed in to a Windows 2003 server and I was wondering what the command line is to show all users who are currently connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from command prompt type

net sessions